# Canonical way to monitor the status of a thread

Tags: java, swing, scala, concurrency, progress-bar

I'm using Scala to write a GUI application in Swing that starts multiple threads to download files via HTTP concurrently. I'd like to use a number of `JProgressBar`s to display the status of the downloads. Obviously, the progress bars have to be updated from the event dispatching thread and besides, I would like to keep the HTTP download code separate from the GUI.

I'm wondering what the best way to do this would be? `SwingWorker` is Swing specific and `Observable` seems somewhat archaic in that the parameter passed to the observer is an object and would have to be cast. Scala is a powerful modern language so I was hoping there's a simpler way to do what I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [connect jProgressbar with Download process in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420778/connect-jprogressbar-with-download-process-in-java), and [Java ProgressMonitorInputStream using existing JProgressBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379398/java-progressmonitorinputstream-using-existing-jprogressbar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved what I wanted by implementing my own listener callback system using Scala closures. The following code goes in the Download class:

```
val listeners = new ListBuffer[Int => Unit]

def registerListener(f: Int => Unit) {
  if (!listeners.contains(f)) {
    listeners.append(f)
  }
}
```

and this goes in a nested SwingWorker in the GUI:

```
downloader.registerListener(this.listener)

def listener(progress: Int) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable {
    def run() {
      progressBar.setValue(progress)
      table.repaint()
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let your class that downloads accept an PropertChangeListener which you notify about download progress. The listener updates the progress bar accordingly.

Comment: addPropertyChangeListener is a member of java.awt.Component and I am looking for a way to do this that doesn't make use of GUI libraries.